# Google OAuth 2.0 offline access

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My app needs to access user's data even when the user is not present. So my request for authorization code includes `access_type=offline` meaning I will get back a refresh token if this is the first time the user authenticates my app. I save the refresh token and use it later on.

Everything works as expected and pretty well. But what bothers me is a statement in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh):

> Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will
>   be issued; one limit per client/user combination, **and another per use across all clients**. You should save refresh tokens in long-term
>   storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. If your
>   application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these
>   limits, in which case older refresh tokens will stop working.

If I understand this correctly, it is possible the refresh token I save to become invalid if the user authorizes too many applications?! Is this correct? How should the application react in such situations? Ask for another refresh token?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** I created a test PHP script that would request refresh tokens from 4 Google clients (by client I mean generated credentials in the Dev console). Three of them are linked to one gmail address and the forth to a different one. For the first email, I generated 2 projects and for the first project, I generated 2 client ids. So:

1. email `X`, project `A`, client id `abc`
2. email `X`, project `A`, client id `def`
3. email `X`, project `B`, client id `mno`
4. email `Y`, project `C`, client id `xyz`

I started the test by requesting a refresh token for each client. Then I requested 24 more refresh tokens for the first client id `abc`. At this point **all** refresh tokens were valid even though for email `X` I had 27 refresh tokens. Then when I requested another refresh token for client with id `abc`, the first one for this client got invalidated, so hitting the 25 token limit per email/client combination. All other tokens were still valid and I managed to generate new tokens for client `def`. This client is for the same project `A` and the same email `X`. So I can't hit the second limit. What do these statements mean is still a complete mistery to me:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration

> If you need to authorize multiple programs, machines, or devices, one
>   workaround is to limit the number of clients that you authorize per
>   user account to 15 or 20. If you are a Google Apps admin, you can
>   create additional admin users and use them to authorize some of the
>   clients.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

> Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will
>   be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and **another per user
>   across all clients**.

Comment: I got word back from one of the Google devs :"I'm not sure what the limit is per user across all clients but I haven't heard of anyone hitting this before. if I find out i'll let you know."  So we are still waiting for official info on what this means.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks. I can't hit any other limits myself either. But it is always better to know for sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually isn't as bad as you think.  **Refresh tokens are application specific**, that meaning specific to your client id.  If the user installs your application a number of times then they have a number of Refresh tokens related to your application.

I ran into this issue with a SSIS Connection manager if the user had my connection manager running on more then 20 SSIS packages the first one the installed would stop working.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration

```
Token expiration

You should write your code to anticipate the possibility that a granted token might
no longer work. 
A token might stop working for one of these reasons:
```

> - The user has revoked access.
> - The token has not been used for six months.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.
>
> There is currently a 25-token limit per Google user account. If a user
>   account has 25 valid  - tokens, the next authentication request
>   succeeds, but quietly invalidates the oldest outstanding token without
>   any user-visible warning.
>
> If you need to authorize multiple programs, machines, or devices, one
>   workaround is to limit the number of clients that you authorize per
>   user account to 15 or 20. If you are a Google Apps admin, you can
>   create additional admin users and use them to authorize some of the
>   clients.

So as long as your application isn't being installed more then 15 times by the same user you shouldn't have a problem.   If it is a problem you can suggest that they use a different / dedicated login for your application.

Comment: Thanks. But are they talking out access or refresh tokens? Also I don't understand this 25 token limits. Say, user martin@gmail.com authorizes my app and then authorizes 25 more apps. Would the refresh token given to my app (the oldest one) be invalidated?

Comment: Its the refresh token they are talking about.  Remember the access token is only good for 1 hour. You use the Refresh token to get a new one.  You can keep getting new Access tokens as often as you like using the Refresh token.  (btw you are right Grant token is a little confusing I will send Google a note about that)

Comment: If user martin@gmail.com authorizes "YOUR APP" 15 -20 times the FIRST refresh token he had with your app would no longer work.  Its your app not someone elses app.

Comment: That's the first constraint `one limit per client/user combination`. But see what the second one says: `and another per use across all clients`?!?! How should I read this?

Comment: GOOD question! I have no idea what they mean by that statement.  But I know who to ask.  I will get back to you on that.

Comment: Here is a guess that I'm testing, you can create more then one client id for your application. I think they are referring to the other client ids you may have created.  So if you have a client id for your app for web and another one for mobile they still count as the same client and both count in the same max 15 - 20.  Creating mini app to test

Comment: I made a PHP script test. Please, see the results in the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: I sent off a question to Google hoping someone could clarify what they mean by that statement.  I haven't heard anything back yet.  If I do I will let you know