# The Google access token can not be updated

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

I'm using Google Identity Platform for an application I'm developing. I've introduced it to many schools.

But in recent years, there is a problem with the system: The access token can not be updated.

(This problem is occurring in many schools and The same problem also occurred in Google Cloud Directory Sync.)

According to Google, the conditions for expiration of the token are as follows:

- The user has revoked access.
- The token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.

But my situation does not match any of the above.  Is there any other reason that I may be having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I've introduced it to many schools.

Based on this statement, you are likely facing the next issue that is described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) directly underneath the bullet points you listed in your question:

> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per Google Account per OAuth 2.0 client ID. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning. This limit does not apply to [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

With the suggested workaround:

> If you need to authorize multiple programs, machines, or devices, one workaround is to limit the number of clients that you authorize per Google Account to 15 or 20. If you are a Google Workspace admin, you can create additional users with administrative privileges and use them to authorize some of the clients.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958995/1072229) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering.I am sorry for the delayed confirmation.

I checked the number of tokens my Google user account has.
However, the number is only 2, which is less than 25. The information you taught does not seem to be related to this issue.

There is no problem with login operation, but password change is not good.
The token which was able to update until the previous day can not be updated suddenly,,

I have been investigating from then, but I do not know.
Lend me your wisdom..